# php session and database in codiegniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I am trying to create shopping cart in codeigniter. can any one suggest me the best way of doing this thing with database and PHP session.

I found lots of thing for it through internet but its not solved my problem.

Please give me shortest way for it.

I am new to codeigniter.

Comment: why creating own shopping cart while ,we have great resource on the internet ,like opencart etc.

Comment: Check the answer post below

Comment: client need website only in codeigniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CodeIgniter provides a default `Cart` class for these purposes.
```

You just have to load the library

```
$this->load->library('cart');
```

If you are using the `CodeIgniter's` `Cart` class it is mandatory that you give `(id, qty, price, and name)` for each products.

Cart class provides ways to `insert` and `update` the items.

Here is the [CodeIgniter's DOCS](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html) on Cart Class

This is the [Tutorial](http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-shopping-cart/) that helped me grasp on how to use the Cart class

Comment: Thanks, i am looking for something like this.

Comment: always a pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

Sample Cart code which i use. Use your own cart option with the help of these code

**Controller**

```
public function  __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');//session library 
        $this->load->model('Model_Name');//model library 
        $this->load->library('cart');//cart library 
    }
```

**Insert data to Cart**

> In shopping cart `id`, `qty`, `price`, `name` *fields are must*

```
public function insert_cart()
    {           
        $data = array(
            'id'    => $this->input->post('id'),
            'qty'   => $this->input->post('qty'),
            'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
            'name'  => $this->input->post('name'),
        );
        $this->cart->product_name_rules = '[:print:]';
        $this->cart->insert($data);
    }
```

**Remove data to Cart**

```
    function remove($rowid)
    {
        if ($rowid==="all")
        {
            $this->cart->destroy();
            redirect('index.php/main');//relevent page
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array(
                'rowid'   => $rowid,
                'qty'     => 0
            );
            $this->cart->update($data);
        }

        // This will show cancle data in cart.
        redirect('index.php/cart');
    }
```

**Update data to Cart**

```
    function update_cart()
    {

        $cart_info =  $_POST['cart'] ;

        foreach( $cart_info as $id => $cart)
        {
            $rowid = $cart['rowid'];
            $qty = $cart['qty'];
            $price = $cart['price'];

            $data = array(
                'rowid'   => $rowid,
                'qty'     => $qty,
                'price'=> $price,
            );
            $this->cart->update($data);
            $this->cart->contents();
        }
        redirect('index.php/cart');
    }
```

[CodeIgniter Shopping Cart](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html)

[Example from Google](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-build-a-shopping-cart-using-codeigniter-and-jquery--net-8187)

Comment: Thanks, abdulla i am trying both of the answer  given here.